# iMessage workflow for incoming texts from someone?

Tags: macos, iphone, mac, messages

Are there any ways to start *any* sort of workflow based on incoming iMessage texts?

When I'm at work, I usually have my iPhone on silent mode. But when my wife texts me, I'd like to figure out *some* way of making her texts more..."alerty". But I'm not even sure the first step (Identify when a text/iMessage comes in from her phone #) is even possible on a Mac using anything from Automator, Applescript, Alfred, Keyboard Maestro, *anything*.

Does anyone know of any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could activate the Emergency Bypass on you iPhone. 
Unfortunately there is no possibility on the mac yet. 
But it would be usable on the iPhone.

1. Launch Contacts from your Home screen and open the contact you want Emergency Bypass on.
2. Tap Edit.
3. Tap Ringtone.
4. Tap the Emergency Bypass switch. The switch should be green when it's enabled.
5. Tap
   Done.
6. Tap Done again.